# Suggestion for finding answer to this question

Tags: discussion

This question was closed

[Point and click proxy/vpn as usage workaround [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/398965/point-and-click-proxy-vpn-as-usage-workaround)

(Just updated the questions title to "Workaround for API limits" in an attempt to make the question more clear.)

And though I realize it might be asked better, believe it's clear how the question is asking for help, and what the problem is. Beyond that, it's unclear to me why the question is off-topic, and if it is, which SE it might be the best fit for, and how I might improve the question.

If the question is unclear, if possible please restate you current understanding of how the question is asking for help, and what the problem is that I'm facing so that I might better understand where the problems are with the question. Thanks!

Comment: I still can't figure out what you want.  As for writting hints see my answer here. http://meta.serverfault.com/a/2178/984

Comment: @Zoredache: Thanks, I read your post on better writing and attempt to make use of it too. As for the answer, maybe this will help. The common answer to this problem is to "go blackhat" and figure out a way to hide that I'm the same system accessing the API. I'm not trying to hide anything, and believe each client should be have their API access tied to them. Only solution I've thought of is to have each client install a proxy on their network to limit API based on their usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It should have been closed as Not Constructive as you're essentially polling for options. There is no one Correct Answer, you just want suggestions alternative to your current idea. I can't think of any way to reword this as a valid question; though I find I'm caffeine deficient this morning.
2. It's really not clear what exactly you're trying to get at. Do you want to access 3rd party APIs that your client's contract you to manage using both the client's IP and User/Login?
3. It sounds like you write the same way you speak. This is bad. Oral communication has the benefit of pace, tone, body language; a million additional factors that make it easier to understand. Text communication has none of this. You should write the way you want it to be read.

Comment: +1 @Chris S: Thanks for the feedback. You're correct, in my attempt to be open to possible suggestions to the problem, it appears I did turn it into a polling question; which is bad. As for what I'm getting at, basically I want my limits/usage tied to their networks, not mine. Having them install a proxy seems like the only solution, but also seems complex and difficult to get done. Guessing this is not a problem unique to me, but attempting to avoid grey/black hat approaches to the problem.

Comment: As for my writing, I'm pretty much self-taught, and have yet to figure out a way to greatly increase the effectiveness of my written communications; in fact, part of the reason I use SE is to practice.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem you are trying to solve is more of a system design/development issue. As such SF is the wrong site. It's also wrong for SO because it's not directly a programming issue. I really don't know what, if any, SE site would be appropriate but it may be worth browsing them because I'm not familiar with them all, so there may well be one.